# opening a WordPress Post in a Modal Window

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the following code which opens a Wordpress post inside an ajax modal which seems to work ok.

The problem is that I also want the post navigation to work inside the modal but it seems like the `jquery` code becomes obsolete once it's been run once.

Is there any way to keep the code working even after it's been run? it seems like the post content inside the modal ignores the `onclick` code.

Hope that makes sense,

```
(function($) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".esg-grid a, .postmodal a").click(function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
        var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");

            //$(".postmodal").load(post_url);
                $(".postmodal").load(post_url + " #main-content" );
                $(".postmodal-container").removeClass("hidden");
                //window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
    return false;
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` event does not work on the dynamically loaded links, because they were not there in the moment of `document.ready`. You need to use delegated event handling:

```
$(document).on("click", ".esg-grid a, .postmodal a", function(event) {
   // the body of your callback
});
```

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you :)

Comment: Is there a simple way i can make the modal scroll to the top when a nav link is clicked ?